# Can we configure cloud schedular to run a job in future?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want cloud schedular to run a job every 1 minute after 5 hours of jobs creation time.

so if I create a job at 3 PM, I want it to run every 1 minute starting at 8 PM, I am using cloud run to create this Job so I don't have the option of creating the job after 5 hours as the cloud run container is alive only during req/res cycle.

Is there a way in GCP through which we can achieve this ?

Comment: You want to perform job every minute indefinitely 5h after the first job run?

Comment: Not indefinitely, but once the job runs 5-10 times, it will be deleted programatically

Comment: Have you tried [configuring a Cloud Run job to execute on a schedule](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs-on-schedule#using-scheduler) if this would fit your needs?

Comment: If it's 5 - 10 times, you could simply create delayed Cloud Task. It's simpler than create and delete a Scheduler!

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere but the problem is my tasks might take more than 30 min to complete and the cloud task can wait for response from worker for maximum 30 minutes

Comment: Thanks @RobertG but It needs to happen programmatically so I can't manually configure it, I am exploring ways to create & delete cloud schedular job using node sdk

Answer (score 0):

As per @guillaume blaquiere's comment, you could use Google Cloud Tasks. Based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview):

> Cloud Tasks lets you separate out pieces of work that can be performed independently, outside of your main application flow, and send them off to be processed, asynchronously, using *handlers* that you create.
>
> The offloaded task is added to a *queue*, which persists the task until it is successfully executed.

Cloud Tasks triggers actions based on how the individual task object is configured. You may check the [comparison of Cloud Tasks to Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/comp-tasks-sched).

You may also check this documentation on [Asynchronous Code Execution with Google Cloud Tasks](https://medium.com/google-cloud/asynchronous-code-execution-with-google-cloud-tasks-9b73ceaf48c3) for additional information.